# Is there a way to copy and paste slides in Preview?

Tags: preview

I'm editing a presentation that's saved to pdf in Preview.  I want to copy a slide and paste it back in several times so I can annotate it in different ways.  Is there a simple way to do that?  Normal copy and paste doesn't work.  At the moment, I'm duplicating the document and dragging and dropping the same slide from the new copied document back into the original.

Comment: Try exporting the slide from PDF as a JPEG, then insert the JPEG into your presentation as many times as you need. Are you using Keynote? Powerpoint?